# SQL condition on unioned tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, union

I'm trying to execute a query with union and then put an additional condition on the result. Basically, I want to have something like

> SELECT * FROM (A UNION B) WHERE condition

Is this possible to do? When I try to execute

> SELECT * FROM (A UNION B)

SQL Management Studio complains about the closing bracket:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM A
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM B
) temp 
WHERE condition
```

Comment: Thanks Luc, I see what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select from A
      UNION
      select from B
     ) ab
WHERE condition;
```

I agree that the original syntax "looks right" for a `from` statement, but SQL doesn't allow it.  Also, you need an alias on the subquery (requirement of SQL Server).  Finally, you might consider using `union all`, if you know there are no duplicates in tables.

Answer (score 1):

how about with CTE:

```
with tbl as (
   select * from a 
   union 
   select * from b) 
select * from tbl where condition
```

Comment: I prefer your answer than mine. `with` is still not natural to me.

Comment: Thats funny since I'm still used to your way too, but recently I have been pushing myself to use more CTE. Sometimes CTE is just to much on the screen and they end up the same to the compiler...

Answer (score 0):

Use alias for derived table

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from A UNION select * from B) as t WHERE condition
```